# How do I filter CloudFormation stacks by tag value?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-cli, jmespath

I want to get the stack name of all CloudFormation stacks with the following tag/value:

`elasticbeanstalk:environment-name` : `myenvironment`

Is there any way to do this? I tried this query but it throws a syntax error:

```
aws cloudformation describe-stacks --query 'Stacks[].Tags[?Key == `elasticbeanstalk:environment-name` && ?Value == `myenvironment`]'
```

### Edit

I figured out the filtering part but I can't figure out how to get the stack name. This returns null, how do I retrieve the StackName?

```
aws cloudformation describe-stacks --query 'Stacks[].Tags[?Key == `elasticbeanstalk:environment-name` && Value == `myenv`].{MyStack: StackName}'
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This was quite an ass pain. I look forward to writing jmespath queries less than regex

```
aws cloudformation describe-stacks --query 'Stacks[?Tags[?Key == `elasticbeanstalk:environment-name` && Value == `myenvname`]].{StackName: StackName}' --output text
```

Comment: In Windows cmd, got it running with  ' and ` replaced, like so:

aws cloudformation describe-stacks --query "Stacks[?Tags[?Key == 'elasticbeanstalk:environment-name' && Value == 'myenvname']].{StackName: StackName}" --output text

Comment: Note to other,  and write your query locally using `jp`:  https://github.com/jmespath/jp. It'll save a tones of time not to have to query AWS every single time.